# How to pretty print value returned by Option in scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-zeppelin

I have a function which returns an "Option[myDataStructure].
When I call this from Zeppelin notebook, it says that it cannot call "show()" on the value as it of type "option". 
Is there any other way using which I can pretty print my returned value as a dataset? 
Printing using `println` is really clumsy.

```
val returnValue: Option[myDataStructure] = myFunction(a,b)
returnValue.show(10,false)
```

Comment: What is `show()`? Is that a method defined on `myDataStructure`? If so, you could do `returnValue.fold( showNone(10, false) ) (_.show(10, false))` (you have to decide how you want to show a missing value).

Comment: `show` is probably referring to the method on **Spark** `DataFrame`. I would use: `returnValue.fold( showNone(println('no data")) { df => df.show(10, false) }`.

Comment: Show is method on Spark DataFRame. however, the value returned is not a DataFrame. Is there anyway where I can convert my ```set[MyDataStructure]``` to ```dataset[MyDataStructure]``` ? IT would let me call show() on the dataset and print values in a readable format.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `foreach` to perform side-effecting action on `Option`:

```
returnValue.foreach(_.show(10,false))
```

It will only run if the `Option` is `Some` and therefore it's safer than calling `get` which may throw `java.util.NoSuchElementException` in the case when `Option` is `None`.

Answer (score -1):

You can get the value in the Option by using the get

```
returnValue.get.show(10,false)
```

Comment: It’ll blow up if returnValue is None. It is better to use foreach() approach as suggested by @Krzysztof in the answer above